# WFA - Button Enable

Tags: c#

in Windows Forms App project, I'm trying to set the enable property of the button control with a custom class - ButtonEnable. The class is static and has one static void method. I am using the method in Form Load event where I try to set the buttons according to my needs, although none of the buttons get changed. Any idea why?

public static class ButtonEnable
{

```
    public static void ButtonSet(bool addButton, bool ediButton, bool saveButton, bool 
    deleteButton, bool cancelButton)
    {
        Form1 form1 = new Form1();

        form1.add_Button.Enabled = addButton;
        form1.edit_Button.Enabled = ediButton;
        form1.save_Button.Enabled = saveButton;
        form1.delete_Button.Enabled = deleteButton;
        form1.cancel_Button.Enabled = cancelButton;
    }

}
```

This is the form load event where I try to the static method

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'test4DB.phone_book_table' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
        this.phone_book_TableAdapter.Fill(this.test4DB.phone_book_table);

        CustomClasses.ButtonEnable.ButtonSet(true, false, false, false, false);

    }
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: where do you call this static method exactly? Form load event of Form1 class?

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by "WFA".... if you're referring to WinForms then that's called just _WinForms_, there's no "A" in there.

Comment: I think now its more clear

Answer (score 1):

You create a new instance of Form1 in your method, this is destroyed when the method ends and has no effect on the other instance where Form1_Load belongs to.

You can pass the object into the method:

```
public static void ButtonSet(Form1 form1, bool addButton, bool ediButton, bool saveButton, bool 
    deleteButton, bool cancelButton)
    {
        form1.add_Button.Enabled = addButton;
        form1.edit_Button.Enabled = ediButton;
        ...
```

and call it like this in Form1_Load

```
CustomClasses.ButtonEnable.ButtonSet(this, true, false, false, false, false);
```

Comment: Knew that I was doing a rookie mistake but my mind went completely blank. Thanks for your response

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 approaches you can implement:

1. If it is a simple project with only one form, don't use static class and method. Instead define a normal method in your Form1 class that manipulates the properties of its buttons.

```
public partial class Form1: Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.phone_book_TableAdapter.Fill(this.test4DB.phone_book_table);

        this.ButtonSet(true, false, false, false, false);
    }

    public void ButtonSet(bool addButton, bool ediButton, bool saveButton, bool 
    deleteButton, bool cancelButton)
    {
        this.add_Button.Enabled = addButton;
        this.edit_Button.Enabled = ediButton;
        this.save_Button.Enabled = saveButton;
        this.delete_Button.Enabled = deleteButton;
        this.cancel_Button.Enabled = cancelButton;
    }
}
```

2. However if it is mandatory to use a static class and method, you can change the static method signature to have another argument of `Form1` type. This way you can change the properties of that object inside the method.

```
public partial class Form1: Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.phone_book_TableAdapter.Fill(this.test4DB.phone_book_table);

        ButtonEnable.ButtonSet(this, true, false, false, false, false);
    }
}
public static class ButtonEnable
{
    public static void ButtonSet(Form1 myForm, bool addButton, bool ediButton, bool saveButton, bool deleteButton, bool cancelButton)
    {
        myForm.add_Button.Enabled = addButton;
        myForm.edit_Button.Enabled = ediButton;
        myForm.save_Button.Enabled = saveButton;
        myForm.delete_Button.Enabled = deleteButton;
        myForm.cancel_Button.Enabled = cancelButton;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I get it know

Comment: @GogaGate
You're welcome. You can contribute to the community by voting up answers that helped you and accepting the best one; hence helping anyone who might come across this problem in the future.

Comment: I still do not have enough reputation points to do so :(